# Django model reference when using AbstractBaseUser model

Tags: django

I 'm following a tutorial of how to use AbstractBaseUser model in Django project. Now I would like to go one step further by creating other models for example address_book and product.

When using defaulter user model, we put like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ....
class AddressBook(models.Model):
   ....
class Product(models.Model):
   ....
```

Now when I use like

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
```

Which reference should I use in the AddressBook and Product class? (The user in the Address book is a foreign key from Class MyUser).

```
 class AddressBook(AbstractBaseUser) and class Product(AbstractBaseUser) or

 class AddressBook(models.Model) and class Product (models.model)?
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: [`Relationship fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python if you define a class like that

```py
class ClassName(SuperClassName):
  ...
```

You are extending one or more existing classes. This is **inheritance**, not a **reference**.

If you want a reference you might want something like this:

```py
class AddressBook(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ...
```

For more detailed information I recommend looking at [this page in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: Hi SvenTUM, thanks for your reply. Based on your answer, do I have to put class Meta: abstract=True? under the AddressBook class?

Comment: Hi @smoothy ! No, need for that. Django Models are pretty straight forward.
You might want to get informed about Object Oriented Programming (OOP). That will include concepts like **inheritance**, **abstract classes**, etc.